# How do we disable "captions settings" in a video.js player?

Tags: html, video.js

I am using video.js 5.7.1 on a single video player within a web page. The video element contains a "captions" track element. When the user clicks the CC button in IE 11, they see a menu containing the following:

- captions settings
- captions off
- english

I would like to completely remove the first menu item "captions settings" so that the menu only shows "captions off" and "english".

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to find how to disable/remove the "captions settings" menu item. What needs to happen to remove this option from the CC button on the player?

For now, I'm setting the track kind to "subtitles" instead of "captions", to avoid the settings menus entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding the following CSS after the video.js CSS:

```
/* Prevent CC settings menu item from displaying */
.vjs-texttrack-settings {
  display: none;
}
```

This accomplished what I needed; the captions settings menu item no longer appears on the CC menu. This works in 5.7.1 and 5.8.8.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes here looking to hide *all* of the caption settings this should work:

```
.vjs-caption-settings {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I posted this same question to video js forum on github:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3202#issuecomment-202540661
The Videojs folks posted solutions - here is the solution I used based on theirs:
after the player started up, I made that problematic area invisible with css:

```
$(".vjs-texttrack-settings").css("display","none");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11909118)

Comment: If you have problems deleting your answer, there is a delete button right there.

Comment: @Mohit I think he tray to answer, although his answer isn't considering all things (like it will hide all the elements).